# jQuery to pause YouTube video stops working when I create a new function.

Tags: jquery, youtube

I need to pause an embedded youtube video on my page. The following placed within the `$youtubeVideos.each(function () {` function works fine:

```
          $('#click').click(function () {
            player.pauseVideo()
          });
```

However when I try and create a separate function to make things more modular it doesn't work. Its in the same place in the code.

```
          function pauseTheVid() {
            player.pauseVideo();
          }
          $('#click').click(function () {
            pauseTheVid;
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$('#click').click(function () {
            pauseTheVid();
          });
```

**NOTE:** The parenthesis while calling the function